# Upload a video captions file to Facebook?

Tags: facebook, http, facebook-graph-api

According to Facebook's [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/captions/) and this bug [report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1470577926590877) the contents of the .srt file should be in the captions_file parameter. I have tried doing this, but continue to get the error:

```
facebookSDK.GraphAPIError: (#100) Invalid file. Expected file of one of the following types: application/octet-stream
```

This is the same error Facebook user Ravi mentions in the bug report. What am I doing wrong? Do the file contents need to be converted to binary? Does a Content-Type:application/octet-stream header need to be added? What specifically needs to be sent via HTTP request?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - used the Facebook's SDK for PHP this is actually a bug in the Facebook SDK , solved it by extending the FacebookFile class used for upload

I use the following when trying to upload a captions file :

```
class FacebookCaptionsFile extends \Facebook\FileUpload\FacebookFile
{
    /**
     * override the original method since srt is not amongst the known file types in the facebook Mimetypes
     */
    public function getMimetype()
    {
        return 'application/octet-stream';
    }
}
```

and the call :

```
public static function uploadCaptions($appId, $appSecret, $accessToken, $videoId, $filePath, $locale)
    {
        if (!file_exists($filePath))
            throw new Exception("Captions file given does not exist: ".$filePath);
        //create file name in format: filename.locale.srt
        $newFilePath = basename($filePath, '.'.pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)).'.'.$locale.'.srt';
        copy($filePath, $newFilePath);
        $data = array (
            'captions_file' => new FacebookCaptionsFile($newFilePath),
        );
        self::helperChangeVideo($appId, $appSecret, $accessToken, $data, $videoId, false, "/captions" );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I logged a bug to Facebook about this and the solution was to use locally stored file instead of URL. For example:

```
curl -i -X POST -F "captions_file=@\"subs.bg_BG.srt\"" https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/***/captions?access_token...
```